# Since PTAB has been formed, what percentage of patents have been invalided due to being retroactively deemed "Obvious"?

Tags: non-obviousness, ptab

This question is motivated by this https://bannerwitcoff.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Jump-Rope-Maker-Gets-PTAB-To-Nix-Rivals-Handle-Patents-Law360.pdf

If there is statistics, what percentage of patent invalidations made by PTAB are due to retroactively deeming the invention to be "Obvious"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy statistics for me to find were based on finding one or more claims invalid. That might be due to subject matter, novelty or obviousness issues.

A group called US Inventors, who are very critical, of the PTAB, have looked at the numbers the USPTO puts out and provided their own wind-age to them. Their analysis  is [here](https://usinventor.org/ptab-statistics/).

They conclude that about half the patents that are challenged have an IPR instituted and about 85% of those proceedings that end with a determination have at least one claim invalidated.

One thing to keep in mind is that a company worried about being found to be infringing will spend at least 10x the time and dollars searching for prior art that the combined efforts of the applicant and the examiner.

As an example, I had been an executive at a large technology company where I worked on multiprocessor technology. After I left an outside law firm called me and asked if had any documents in my garage that they could send someone to sift through looking for prior art for some pending case. Neither an applicant or the examiner do anything to that depth.

If new art is uncovered the odds of showing something as not novel or obvious can dramatically increase.

The more fine grained data you are looking for might be somewhere at the USPTO site or a blog like PatentlyO. To explore further yourself, the PTAB has a site https://developer.uspto.gov/ptab-web/#/search/decisions

where you can search for cases. I tried setting the issue to 103 (obviousness) and clicked on the "Board Decision" tab to order the cases by disposition. You might count Affirmed vs Reversed. Note another category Reversed with new grounds of rejection.

Comment: Of those 85%, is there any statistics on the reason? What percentage were due to being considered obvious?

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct I think the linked article is pretty authoritative. You are asking someone here to generate their own statistics which is an enormous undertaking.

Comment: I added a link to a PTAB site that might be helpful but not easy to use.